# Undefined class 'required' even after updating both dart and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, version, required

When trying to use the required keyword in a constructor, dart tells me "Undefined class 'required'". After looking at a stackoverflow answer, it seemed like I needed to update my flutter/dart versions, but even after I did so, I still got that error.

Here the code with the error:

```
class DropdownValue<T> {
  final String name;
  final T value;
  DropdownValue({required this.name, required this.value});
}
```

Here are my updated versions:

```
Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f1875d570e (6 days ago) • 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

[image]

I already ran `flutter upgrade` and `flutter pub get` as well.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: @nvoigt Sure, I added it, but there's not much to it - I doubt that it's a code issue.

Comment: What's T in this ?

Comment: @KaushikChandru the T is how you create classes like List, Map, etc giving them a type. Look for "dart generics". About the question, I'm not sure, I would reinstall the SDK if I were you.

Comment: Yeah i know its a generic type. Wanted to know what type are you creating. Btw i tried your code and it isnt throwing an error. Your sdk seems to have an issue. Maybe try invalidate cache

Comment: @KaushikChandru How do I invalidate cache? I'm using VSCode

Comment: @FelipeMorschel Dumb question perhaps, but which SDK- Dart, Flutter, Android? I assume Dart? What would be the easiest way of doing so without having tons of problems or leftover artifacts down the road?

Comment: Try `flutter pub cache clean` But please note that you may have to run flutter pub get in all projects after that

Comment: I would suggest trying @KaushikChandru's last answer first. But my suggestion was concerning Flutter SDK unless you've installed Dart on itself, in which case you could try doing that to Dart only. If you're doing, let's say, Flutter reinstall, you could only find where you've installed it and delete that folder. Downloading it there back again. If something doesn't work, you can follow the installation guide again.

Comment: Do you get this error if you run flutter run at the command line?